# fatal: Could not read from remote repository errors on newly created another Github account

Tags: github

I'm trying to push some files to my new(second) Github account through terminal. I've tried so many times with similar questions, but it keeps saying this below

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

To be more specific, at first, I had a Github account(First) and I was able to do 'push' or 'pull' function using SSH URL, but this problem happens when I try to push some files to a new repository of the new account(Second). I've also tried removing the URL, but still it didn't work, and now I'm at a loss about what to do.

Someone said I can use Https URL instead of SSH URL, but I want to resolve this problem not avoiding things that happened.

Thanks!:D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SSH authentication keys are only valid for an Account.

If you made a new Github account and create the repository with this account, you will need to grant read permission at least for your first Github account to be able to access it.

Comment: Yeah, I used different SSH keys when I'm using the accounts. Is there any way to give access to a new GitHub account? or command?

Comment: You can go through HTTP. Normally, if you are using the right SSH Keys, you should be able to pull. Maybe try to give read permission to your original account and try clone the repo again. If it works, that would mean you are using the wrong SSH Keys.